# Cannot combine `if` statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to put two `if` statements together in php but only one of them is executed

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST["redeembutton"])) {
            $redeemedBalance = strip_tags($_POST["vidcoinamount"]);
            $actualBalance = get_balance();

                if ($actualBalance < $redeemedBalance && $redeemedBalance < 500) { // If trying to redeem what the user don't have OPEN ?>
                <span class='greeting'>Sorry, you can't exchange that...</span><br/>
                <span class='heading'>You have <?php echo $row['balance']; ?> Beezes that you can exchange here.</span><br/>
                <span class='heading'>Enter the amount you wish to redeem and hit submit.</span><br/>
                <form class="btcregform" action='redeem.php' method='post'>
                    <input class="btcregforminput" type='text' value='' id='vidcoinamount' name='vidcoinamount'>
                    <input class="btcregformbutton" type='submit' value='Submit'                   id='button' name='redeembutton'>
                </form>
                <?php // If trying to redeem what the user don't have CLOSE
                } else { ?>  
                <?php
                    // Redeem amount is OK OPEN
                    $walletID = get_wallet_id();
                    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $ipadr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    $iscomplete = 'No';
                    $deductamount = $actualBalance-$redeemedBalance;
                    // Get current BTC price from BlockChain into $btcprice (0,01 usd is virool payment per video) 
                    $btcprice = 0.00004335;
                    // Multiply the redeemed balance with the amount in actual BTC worth 0,01 usd.
                    $valueInBTC = $btcprice * $btcprice;
                    // This gets rid of some formatting issues
                    $actualBTC = sprintf("%.10f",$valueInBTC);
                    $setBalance = " UPDATE users SET balance='$deductamount' WHERE username='$username' ";
                    $con = connect();
                    mysqli_query($con, $setBalance) or die ('Couldn\'t set balance to database !');
                    $setRequest = " INSERT INTO requests VALUES ('','$username','$walletID','$redeemedBalance','$actualBTC','$date','$ipadr','$iscomplete') ";
                    mysqli_query($con, $setRequest) or die ('Couldn\'t set payment request for admin into database !');
                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
                <span class='greeting'>Thank you!</span><br/>
                <span class='heading'>Your exchange request has been received.</span><br/>
                <span class='heading'>Please give us up to 48 hours to process it. On weekends it may take longer...</span><br/>
                                <span class='heading'>You have <b><?php print get_balance(); ?></b> Beezes left in your account</span><br/>
                                <br>
<?php
$dollars = get_balance()  / 100;
?>
<?php print get_balance(); ?> Beezes = $<?php print $dollars; ?><br>
                <?php } //If redeem amount is OK CLOSE ?>
        <?php } else { // If the user hasn't done anything yet OPEN ?>
        <span class='greeting'>Redeem your Beezes</span><br/>
        <span class='heading'>Enter the amount you wish to redeem and hit submit.</span><br/>
        <form class="btcregform" action='redeem.php' method='post'>
            <input class="btcregforminput" type='text' value='' id='vidcoinamount' name='vidcoinamount'><br><br>
            <input class="btcregformbutton" type='submit' value='Submit' id='button' name='redeembutton'>
        </form>
        <?php } //If the user hasn't done anything yet CLOSE ?>
```

my problem is that part

```
if ($actualBalance < $redeemedBalance && $redeemedBalance < 499)
```

If the actualbalance is more than the redeemedBalance it works but the part if the redeemedBalnce is less than 500 is not being executed it acts like it's not even there. Please help (newbie here)

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the if statement?

Comment: It didn't work, now it ignore the actualBalance but execute the redeemedBalance < 500 part

Comment: Take a look at your values. I'm having no problem with the correct output.

Comment: Its working in my machine. Give some example values for variables.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest I have problem udnerstading the values, but maybe this will help:

```
<?php

$balance = 1500;
$price = 500;

 if ($balance >= $price) {  echo "There You go...."; }
 else {  echo "Sorry, You cant..."; } 


?>
```

edited.

Comment: take a look at the full script now